# Alternate for 'fn' key in pyAutoGui in Linux

Tags: python, python3

When I use 'fn' key in pyautogui it does'nt work
What is the alternative for that key?

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>fn</kbd> key on laptops are usually directly wired to the embedded controller (EC), and doesn't produce keypress events at all (you can check with `evtest` or `xev`).

Details vary from laptop to laptop.

Which means you cannot use them as you use other keys, you cannot reprogram them as you can other keys, you cannot use it as a modifier key as you can with other keys.

Doesn't matter if it's for `pyautogui`, or something else.